# bin() adx scalar function returns an aggregate every round hour but I want it to be on the half hour

Tags: azure, kusto-explorer

| take 2000000
| summarize Value = avg(Value) by bin(TimeStampOfValue, 1h)

I have an adx table with Value and a Timestamp and I run this query I get the avg Value every hour for example:

| TimeStampOfValue | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-30T22:00:00 | 500 |
| 2022-01-30T23:00:00 | 499,99 |

I'd like it to return:

| TimeStampOfValue | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-30T22:30:00 | 500 |
| 2022-01-30T23:30:00 | 499,99 |

How do I shift the 'by bin' by 30 minutes? so it runs hourly on the half hour mark? Is this even possible?

One solution is to use 'bin_at' with a specific time so it starts hourly from there, is this the only way?

Comment: Why are you reluctant using bin_at?

Comment: For anyone finding this question, just use bin_at.